# HtmlHelper to consume html/text inside using

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm trying to make an HTML helper that will allow for any text inside a using to be consumed and not written to the final page.

The Razor:

```
<div>
    <p>
        Before Inline
    </p>

    @using (Html.IncludeInlineScript("testScript"))
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("hello world");
        </script>
    }

    <p>
        After Inline
    </p>
</div>
```

The resulting HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>
        Before Inline
    </p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("hello world");
        </script>
<!-- Top of Dispose -->
<!-- Bottom of Dispose -->

    <p>
        After Inline
    </p>
</div>
```

The Helper Extension Method:

```
public static ScriptWrapper IncludeInlineScript(this HtmlHelper helper, string scriptName)
{
    return new ScriptWrapper(helper);
}
```

The Wrapper:

```
public class ScriptWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private HtmlHelper _helper;
    private TextWriter _originalWriter;
    private StringBuilder _scriptContents;

    public ScriptWrapper(HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        _helper = helper;
        _originalWriter = _helper.ViewContext.Writer;

        _scriptContents = new StringBuilder();
        _helper.ViewContext.Writer = new StringWriter(_scriptContents);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteLine("<!-- Top of Dispose -->");
        _helper.ViewContext.Writer.Flush();
        _helper.ViewContext.Writer = _originalWriter;
        _originalWriter.WriteLine("<!-- Bottom of Dispose -->");
    }
}
```

The problem here is that despite setting the `ViewContext.Writer` to a new TextWriter it still is writing to the original writer.  Clearly the dispose is being invoked in the right order as the top of the dispose is after the script.  While debugging after the new writer has been set the `<script>` block is not in the stream, however at the time of the dispose the `<script>`is now contained in the original writer.

Is the razor engine keeping a local copy of the writer and ignores the fact that it had been set to a different instance?  This seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wants a work around, since I'm impatient, I found a way to make this work.  It's less than ideal, but it does the trick.  If you modify the `ScriptWrapper` to be:

```
public class ScriptWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private HtmlHelper _helper;
    private string _originalString;
    private StringBuilder _sb;

    public ScriptWrapper(HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        _helper = helper;
        _sb = ((StringWriter) _helper.ViewContext.Writer).GetStringBuilder();
        _originalString = _sb.ToString();
        _sb.Clear();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var contents = _sb.ToString();
        _sb.Clear();
        _sb.Append(_originalString);
    }
}
```

You can accomplish the desired result of consuming anything inside the `using(...)` statement.

I would however still be curious to know if there is a way to do it without hacking a solution like this.

Answer (score 0):

In your original (the question), it's tempting to think that because the markup is within the using block, somehow ScriptWrapper is consuming the markup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("hello world");
</script>
```

but as you found out, it is *not* being consumed by the `ScriptWrapper` in any way. You are hoping that this markup would get "redirected" somewhere else, to the writer you create, but it isn't.  Instead the writer you create is also used to write to the response stream, which is what the `ViewContext.Writer` is used for, whatever writer it happens to be.

So, rather than having ScriptWrapper consume the markup, Razor is interpreting it as markup like anything else in the view and is, after interpreting it, writing it to the Response stream.  From Razor's perspective that markup is intended for the output, not for ScriptWrapper. Just having it enclosed in a using block, does not make the markup any less a part of the overall view.

You answer succeeds because you are not redirecting the markup to somewhere else (which doesn't work), but because you are editing what ends up in the response stream, effectively erasing the markup from the response stream.

I would argue that your solution is not a hack but a correct way of approaching this, given what you want to accomplish.

Comment: What you said would be right if the TextWriter I created wrote that value into its string builder.  Instead the original writer got the value despite no longer being attached to the ViewContent.  I still think this is a defect in the MVC5 framework.